# Abrir div ao passar mouse por cima do input text

Tags: css

Eu tenho esta div, onde o input text está dentro:

```
   <div class="col-md-4" id="passarmouse">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="FornecedorID" onkeypress="return BuscaDados(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor(this.value);" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor" />
                    </div>
```

E essa é a div que eu preciso que mostre, ao passar o mouse na div `passarmouse`,

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="mostrar">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor"></label>
                    <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor"></label>
                    <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Tentei por `css` porém não está dando certo:

```
    #mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#passarmouse:hover #mostrar {
    display: block;
}
```

Como posso resolver? Pensei em colocar tipo um modal então.

Comment: se `#mostrar` não é descendente de `#passarmouse` não funciona, pois o teu seletor CSS é de descendência, ou seja, *para qualquer elemento que tenha id 'mostrar' e que tenha um descendente com o id '#passarmouse' aplique as propriedades abaixo.*.

Comment: você não pode fazer um seletor (por exemplo #passarmose) selecionar outro elemento (#mostrar). você consegue agir no próprio elemento do seletor ou num dos filhos no máximo, o que você quer fazer vai precisar usar `javascript`

Comment: Cara já tento usar o evento onFocus do javascript para isso?

Comment: Se div #mostrar vem logo depois da div #passarmouse, isso deve funcionar `#passarmouse:hover + #mostrar {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: @Thayllervilelacintra não tentei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atere seu  css para

```css
#mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#passarmouse:hover + #mostrar {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4" id="passarmouse">
     <input type="text" asp-for="FornecedorID" onkeypress="return BuscaDados(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor(this.value);" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor" />
 </div>
                    
<div class="col-md-4" id="mostrar">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor">aaa</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor">bbb</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor">ccc</label>
     <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor">ddd</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor">eee</label>
      <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor">fff</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ao adicionar  o  sinal  de  mais você estará indicando que o evento deve ser adicionado a div mostrar

Comment: O `+` é o [seletor de elemento adjacente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), não implica de maneira nenhuma que o evento deve ser adicionado à div `#mostrar`. As regras CSS sempre são aplicadas ao seletor mais a direita.

Comment: @fernandosavio >> http://jsfiddle.net/ego3cafh/ funcionando desta forma

Comment: Marcos, não estou dizendo que o código não funcionará (apesar do Fiddle não estar funcionanado). O que estou dizendo é que não adianta dar um código funcionando e explicar errado o porquê de estar funcionando. Não existem eventos sendo adicionados ao `#mostrar`. O `#mostrar` simplesmente satisfaz o seletor que é ser um elemento adjacente e posterior a um elemento `#passarmouse` que esteja no estado de `:hover`.

Comment: @fernandosavio na verdade até está funcionando, só que por algum motivo ele colocou o texto na cor branca, ai não parece quando faz o :hover pq o fundo tb é branco. O que ele podia fazer é dar uma explicação melhor mesmo, citar links de apoio etc, mas ele tb não é obrigado a isso, vai de cada um...

Comment: @MarcosBrinner não funcionou no meu exemplo, achei que era porque tinha uma outra div do lado, que estava atrapalhando ela de aparecer, porém mesmo sem ela, não funciona.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer que é para ser uma crítica construtiva para não confundir quem ler a resposta. Não é nenhum ataque pessoal. @hugocsl, explicar ou não explicar vai de cada um, porém não dá pra fazer uma afirmação que não é verdadeira, pode ser que alguém tome como verdade e aprenda errado. Mas enfim, os comentários estão aí pra isso. Bola pra frente

Comment: Após fechar a div `passarmouse` depois da div `mostrar` o meu código mesmo funcionou.

Comment: excelente, que bom  q  de uma forma ou  de  outra conseguiu  resolve-lo

Comment: E adicionei uma class pra que ele fique flutuante: `.div_teste {
        width: 350px;
        height: 120px;
        background: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 30%;
        left: 40%;
        border: 1px solid;
    }`